# DOM and xml object to be show and hide based on the certain condition

Tags: javascript

I've Yes , no radio button and based on yes no radio button, I need to show and hide certain questions from DOM.

We have radio button which has two values yes, no.
If user clicks yes, parent node needs to be hide and if user clicks no those elements from DOM needs to be show in the page.
Here is what I've so far:

Please let me know if you need more info

```html
function toggleShortStay()
{
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var questiongroupbodyNode;
  var questiongroupNode;
  var oldChild;
  $('#A2400A').change(function(){
   questiongroupbodyNode = document.getElementById('A_SHORTA_wrapper').parentNode;
   questiongroupNode = questiongroupbodyNode.parentNode; 
   var dupNode = document.getElementById("foo").cloneNode(false);
   if($(this).val()== '1')
   {  
    oldChild = questiongroupNode.parentNode.removeChild (questiongroupNode);
   }
   else if($(this).val()== '0')
   {
    document.documentElement.appendChild(oldChild);
   }
  });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put `$(document).ready()` on the first line.

Comment: if($(this).val()== '1') this line works. But my problem is I need to hold the reference before removing so that I can add it back if they select the No option in the page. (else if($(this).val()== '0') I need help with this line

Comment: Maybe you can try just if () { } else { } instead of giving another condition, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to go to parent and parent to get the root and hide it that way. 
         var specialGroup = $('#A_SHORTA_wrapper').parent().parent();
based on a condtion do the show/hide on this div

specialGroup.show();
specialGroup.hide();